# bootstrap-datepicker date vanishes from vue input field when using v-model

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, vue.js

I am using `bootstrap-datepicker` with `vue js`. The problem is, when I select date it comes to the input field but whenever I shift to another input field, the date vanishes. how do I make the date stay even if I switch to another field. below is my code

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha256-bqVeqGdJ7h/lYPq6xrPv/YGzMEb6dNxlfiTUHSgRCp8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span v-bind:style="{ width: prependWidth + 'px' }" class="input-group-text">Acceptance Date</span>
  </div>
  <input data-provide="datepicker" v-model="formData.acceptance_date" id="acceptance_date" name="acceptance_date" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control">
</div>

here is my vue data

formData: { 
                event_name: '',
                ba_alt: '',
                bn_alt: '',
                acceptance_date: ''

            },
```

Comment: What is the another field? another input? or another datepicker?

Comment: ith happens on any other input field on the form.